ImportError and TypeError Issues in Nougat OCR with BARTDecoder and cached_property
I'm facing issues while running an OCR process using Nougat with two different errors for two different users. The errors are related to importing cached_property and an unexpected keyword argument cache_position. Below are the full error messages for both cases:
Error 1: ImportError for cached_property
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'nougat.utils' (/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/utils/__init__.py)
OCRing with base model failed on /lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/massive-evaporation-4-math/data/debug_pdfs/dummy_folder1/The_IMO_Compendium.pdf... trying small model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/bin/nougat", line 5, in <module>
    from predict import main
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/predict.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nougat import NougatModel
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nougat.app import Nougat
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from nougat.asgi import serve
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/asgi.py", line 6, in <module>
    from nougat.context.request import Request
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/context/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nougat.context.request import Request
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/context/request.py", line 8, in <module>
    from nougat.utils import cached_property, File
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'nougat.utils' (/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/utils/__init__.py)
OCRing with small model failed on /lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/massive-evaporation-4-math/data/debug_pdfs/dummy_folder1/The_IMO_Compendium.pdf
The following files failed OCRing and need manual review:
/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/massive-evaporation-4-math/data/debug_pdfs/putnam_and_beyond.pdf
/lfs/skampere1/0/emilyhyf/massive-evaporation-4-math/data/debug_pdfs/dummy_folder1/The_IMO_Compendium.pdf
Time taken: 8.497612476348877 seconds, 0.1416268746058146 minutes, 0.00236044791009691 hours

Error 2: TypeError for cache_position in BARTDecoder
TypeError: BARTDecoder.prepare_inputs_for_inference() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache_position'
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
OCRing with base model failed on /lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/contest_scraper/test_nougat/731991.pdf... trying small model
/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/functional.py:512: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:3587.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs) # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  0%|                                                 | 0/288 [00:24<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/bin/nougat", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/predict.py", line 167, in main
    model_output = model.inference(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nougat/model.py", line 592, in inference
    decoder_output = self.decoder.model.generate(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1758, in generate
    result = self._sample(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/miniconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 2394, in _sample
    model_inputs = self.prepare_inputs_for_generation(input_ids, **model_kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BARTDecoder.prepare_inputs_for_inference() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache_position'
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
-> Cannot close object, library is destroyed. This may cause a memory leak!
OCRing with small model failed on /lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/contest_scraper/test_nougat/731991.pdf
The following files failed OCRing and need manual review:
/lfs/skampere1/0/naveenkc/contest_scraper/test_nougat/731991.pdf
Time taken: 65.70022702217102 seconds, 1.0950037837028503 minutes, 0.018250063061714172 hours

Environment:

Python 3.12
Nougat
Torch
Transformers

Questions:

ImportError: How can I resolve the ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'nougat.utils'? What could be causing this issue, and is there an alternative approach to import cached_property?

TypeError: How can I address the TypeError: BARTDecoder.prepare_inputs_for_inference() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache_position'? Is this due to a version mismatch between transformers and torch? How can I ensure compatibility?


Any guidance on these issues would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Which OS are you experiencing this on ?

As for the first question, there are no such objects within the current library code.
You may want to check yourself.
The maintainers received such alerts two weeks ago, but haven't responsed yet
https://github.com/facebookresearch/nougat/issues/226
As for the second question, the mismatch is between nougat and transformers as pointed out here. The reported solution is to downgrade transformers to the moment before the mismatch occurred, e.g. pip install transformers==4.38.2.
Overall, be prepared for lots of improvisation when working with unmature/ experimental / rapidly developing code. Breaking changes are unavoidable, and users are expected to handle many issues themselves.
